# Load collectionView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous, uicollectionview

Each `UITableViewCell` contains a `UICollectionView` to display images from a list of urls. However, not all images of `collectionView` are displayed. If I go to detail `ViewController` of tapped cell and then go back, that specific cell's `collectionView` is now loaded correctly. Should I call reload data after image is set? Any advice or solution is appreciated.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // set urls
    cell.collectionPhotoURLStrings = photoURLs;
    // reload collectionView
    [cell.collectionView reloadData];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // load image async at indexPath
    [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.photoURLs[indexPath.row]]];
    return cell;
}
```

call method from SDWebImage framework:

```
- (void)sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    // cancel current image load
    [self sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad];
    // get image async
    // ... 
    // set image and layout of self (UIImageView)
    self.image = image;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

I think a solution might be to reload collectionView from the following `willDisplayCell` tableView delegate.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cell.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Where you set Collection view data source.

Comment: @Lenin in TableView Cell

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {


 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 4
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 100
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let   Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! tableCell
    Cell.collectionView.delegate = self
    Cell.collectionView.dataSource = self

    return Cell

}



// MARK: - CollectionView
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! collectionCell

    return cell
}

}
class collectionCell : UICollectionViewCell
{

}
class tableCell: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
}
```

I have share complete code in git repository

Clone the code from this link

https://github.com/leninsmannath/CollectionViewInsideTableViewCell.git

Comment: This doesn't address the real problem, which is handling async tasks while taking tableView and collectionView into consideration.

Comment: I refactored question and added a bit of code to make things more clear.